# Clearing border in second table using css

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created two tables on an html page, I want the first table to have a border but I don't want the second table to have one. How do I make the second table not display a border in CSS?

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

 th {
 background-color: #4B0082;
 color: white;
}


table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
      <tr>
          <td>table 1</td>
        <td>table 1</td> 
        <td><TABLE style="width:100%; border: none;">
    <TR>
               <TD>table 2</TD>
               <TD>table 2</TD>
              </TR>

               <TR>
               <TD>table 2</TD>
               <TD>table 2</TD>
               
    </TR>
       </TABLE></td>
 
    <td>table 1</td> 
    
  </tr>
```

Comment: can you please provide some code  you have tried ????

Comment: code is added to the question

Comment: do you have two different table cz your code seems a bit messy.

Comment: When asked to provide code, we're asking for you to post enough code for us to reproduce your problem; your posted HTML is incomplete. Please read the "*[MCVE],*" and "*[ask],*" guidelines for further help.

Comment: @AsifuzzamanRedoy I did say that in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your code is not clear much ,i am adding a possible answer hope it helps you .use id to identify the tables uniquely.

```css
#t1 tr td  {

border:2px solid;
width:150px;
text-align:center;


}
#t2  {

/*border:2px solid; add border if you want to row*/
width:250px;

}
```

```html
<TABLE id="t1">
           <TR>
           <TD>table 1</TD>
           <TD>table 1</TD>
           <TD>table 1</TD>
           <TD>table 1</TD>        
    </TR>
 <TR>
           <TD>table 1</TD>
           <TD>table 1</TD>
           <TD>table 1</TD>
           <TD>table 1</TD>        
    </TR>
 <TR>
           <TD>table 1</TD>
           <TD>table 1</TD>
           <TD>table 1</TD>
           <TD>table 1</TD>        
    </TR>
   </TABLE>

<br>
<TABLE id="t2">
           <TR>
           <TD>table 2</TD>
           <TD>table 2</TD>
           <TD>table 2</TD>
           <TD>table 2</TD>        
    </TR>
 <TR>
           <TD>table 2</TD>
           <TD>table 2</TD>
           <TD>table 2</TD>
           <TD>table 2</TD>        
    </TR>
 <TR>
           <TD>table 2</TD>
           <TD>table 2</TD>
           <TD>table 2</TD>
           <TD>table 2</TD>        
    </TR>
   </TABLE>
```

Comment: I'm so stupid giving each an ID would be the smartest thing to do

Comment: this didn't work but it might be because the second table is inside the first table?

Comment: I was able to fix the problem myself

Comment: yes But if your table is inside another table  use another id  something like #t1 #tnew{ border:0; } will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my stab at your code
I gave the second table a class name of no-border

```
<table class="no-border">...</table>
```

CSS:

```
.no-border td {border: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For completely remove border**

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

And in css:

table `{border: none;}`

**remove table cell borders**

table `{ border-collapse:collapse }`
**or**

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```